# Rex and identity files

Tags: perl, ssh, openstack, fiware, rex

I'm trying to configure a fi-ware cloud instance using Rex. What these instances (and probably other OpenStack-based systems) prove is a "identity file", a single private key that you can use to connect to them. I have been using variations of this:

```
user "root";
private_key "/home/jmerelo/.ssh/jj-iv.pem";
public_key "/home/one/public/key.dsa";
key_auth;


group fiware => "130.206.x.y";

desc "Install git";
task "git", group => "fiware", sub {
   install "git";
};
```

where the private key is the one provided by fi-ware, and the public key is, well, whatever I thought of, or nothing. 
If no public key is provided, error is

```
[2014-11-30 11:45:45] WARN - Error running task/batch: No public_key file defined. at /home/jmerelo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/lib/site_perl/5.20.0/Rex/Task.pm line 621.
 at /home/jmerelo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/lib/site_perl/5.20.0/Rex/TaskList/Base.pm line 273.
```

which is quite obviously true. But if I try other public keys, error is:

```
[2014-11-30 11:48:37] WARN - Error running task/batch: Wrong username/password or wrong key on 130.206.127.211. Or root is not permitted to login over SSH. at /home/jmerelo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/lib/site_perl/5.20.0/Rex/TaskList/Base.pm line 273.
```

Using

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/jj-iv.pem root@130.206.x.y
```

connects correctly to the instance. So maybe the question is "Can Rex use a single private key to connect to a host?"

Comment: Net::SSH2 (the SSH module used by default by Rex) may not support your key format. [Tell Rex](http://www.rexify.org/howtos/book/authentication.html) to use Net::OpenSSH instead.

Comment: You can also convert the key to a format supported by Net::SSH2. See [this entry](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32768/converting-keys-between-openssl-and-openssh) for instance.

Comment: @salva in fact, eventually the solution was in that page: you can generate a public key from a private key. However, I didn't find how changing the connection mode to a different module could help.

Comment: Under the hood, Net::OpenSSH uses the `ssh` binary, so if you are able to connect from the command line, it is very likely you will also be able go connect using Net::OpenSSH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I generated a public key from the private key using, as suggested [by the documentation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32768/converting-keys-between-openssl-and-openssh),

```
$ sshkey-gen -y -f /path/to/your/private.key >public.key
```

and then using that public.key in the Rexfile